# static assert to check if constructor is explicit

Tags: c++

I'm using the [Catch](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch) unit test library. In one of my test cases, I need to be able to verify that a specific constructor in my class remains `explicit` (In other words, if the `explicit` keyword is removed the test should fail to compile with a helpful/contextual message).

Is this something I can do with `static_assert`? If so, what would be the correct procedure? I have thought about using `static_assert` with something like type traits, but I don't see a way to verify explicit constructors via type traits.

FYI, I have C++14 enabled on GCC 4.9 (NDK & Ubuntu) and on VS 2015 (Windows), just in case "partial-support" is an issue on any of these toolchains/platforms.

Comment: If you can't `static_assert` it, you could always just perform an *implicit* conversion and if it compiles then the constructor is not `explicit`. You just won't have a nice user-defined error message if the constructor *is* explicit.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I need the opposite of your suggestion: It should fail to compile if an implicit conversion is allowed. I'm trying to disallow implicit construction.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Without knowing what your class looks like (and without a background in Catch) it's impossible to give a specific answer, but a general solution using [`std::is_convertible`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible) is fairly simple:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
   Foo(int x) {}
};

struct Bar
{
   explicit Bar(int x) {}
};

int main()
{
   // The `is_convertible` trait checks for implicit convertibility
   std::cout << std::is_convertible<int, Foo>::value << '\n'; // "1"
   std::cout << std::is_convertible<int, Bar>::value << '\n'; // "0"
}
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9afb78439fbf0291))

You just need to assert that the result is `false`, and you're set.

This may be complicated somewhat if your source type is itself a class with a conversion operator, though the thing you're trying to prevent is basically the same in that case anyway.

Comment: I wonder if it's actually possible to write a type trait that differentiates between implicit ctors and conversion operators. Probably there is, I learned to never say never in C++. Great answer btw and congrats for reaching 200k ;).

Comment: @vsoftco: I started writing my own trait for this answer before discovering `is_convertible` by chance, around the same time I realised that I couldn't think of a way to make that distinction. And thanks :D

Comment: There seem to be a proposal, see http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3987.pdf, `is_explicit`.

Comment: Upvote for great answer and congrats on 200k :) Note that I mentioned Catch for context, although it really has nothing to do with the solution (at least, I figured that much). I also didn't provide an example class because the sample is straightforward. Just pick a class with an explicit constructor. The "assertion" should fail if I remove the `explicit` keyword. I will try your sample. Thanks!

Comment: That was quick to verify: It works great!! I have updated your sample [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6dcebeac1add9349).

Comment: @void.pointer: The assertion message is a little misleading but otherwise good.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit If you mean the message does not properly convey what the type trait is doing, that's probably correct, but really just a technicality. Did you mean something else? I wanted the test to make it obvious what the intent was.

Comment: @void.pointer: Yeah I meant that. The outcome is that you could end up with an assertion failure message saying "Foo constructor must be explicit" when that's not what the problem is. I consider it an abstraction leak. Ultimately you need to decide what it is that you want. Why do you care about the constructor being `explicit`? What you really care about is banning implicit conversions, surely.

Comment: What about checking whether a default constructor is explicit? This can be useful to disambiguate tag-like types.